# Using MySQL aggregate functions and UNION operator together

Tags: mysql, union

This is the first time I'm trying UNION operator of MySQL but the following code is giving me an error of "undefined index: female".

```
$sql = "(SELECT COUNT(gender) AS male FROM members WHERE gender='m') 
        UNION 
        (SELECT COUNT(gender) AS female FROM members WHERE gender='f') 
        UNION 
        (SELECT COUNT(gender) AS no_gender FROM members WHERE gender='n') 
        ";
    $results = $con->query($sql);
    if ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        print $row["male"] . "<br>";
        print $row["female"] . "<br>";
        print $row["no_gender"] . "<br>";
    }
```

---

So, based on the solution by fancyPants, the following worked:

```
print "<table>";
$sql = "SELECT gender, COUNT(1) AS no_of_genders 
        FROM members 
        WHERE user_id = $user_id 
        GROUP BY gender";
$results = $con->query($sql);
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    print "<tr><td>" . $row["gender"] . "</td><td>" . $row["no_of_genders"] . "</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: one `'user_id'` with multiple genders ????

Comment: In a union one column has only one name. So all your counts are in column `male` but in different rows.

Comment: @ Ravinder, no_gender is where the member is not a person but some company or institution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT gender, 
COUNT(1) AS no_of_members
FROM members
GROUP BY gender;
```

This produces as much rows as there are different genders in your table.

Comment: Every time I remind myself that I have to learn more SQL, but I forget it till the next time comes.